# How to get click event of android Softkeyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-events

I have a numeric keyboard in my application, I want to get click event of any pressed key, I am using below code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:

            // here my code stuff

            return true;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Here I can not get any other key click event.

Comment: Use KEYCODE_NUM instead of KEYCODE_1 for number inputs.

Comment: @Brendon, i have tried it, even though i could not get anything else, Thanks.

Comment: what is your exact need?

Comment: You have to Use onKeyup or onKeyDown like tat, only OnKey wont work

Comment: @Brendon, actually i have numeric soft keyboard and i want key event of 0 to 9 keys.

Comment: then use onKeyDown with 0 to 9 cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of R & D, i found a point regarding android soft keyboard onKeyListener, this is bug of Android, Please refer this link: [see this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42904), In SDK version 16 and above there is a bug with the KEYCODE_DEL event not being delivered to a OnKeyListener on an edittext. Other events such as DONE and pressing a letter/number key work, but not the KEYCODE_DEL. So finally we can get either Delete button event or get all key event except Delete. Thanks.